# Sorting data extracted by QUERY by a new column in the destination list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am pulling some filtered data out of a master list by QUERY. I am also adding another column, which does not exist in the master list, to the date in the destination list. My question is how should I sort my data by that new column without having it get messed up every time QUERY updates the list?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add some sample data and the formula that you are using. Also you should add a brief description of your search efforts to find helpful content from this site. Ref. [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your intention is to manually add data side-by-side with formula results. That exposes you to the risk of rows getting [misaligned](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649).

You probably should insert the new column to the existing data table instead of adding it to formula results.